# NSFileManager fails to save - No such file or directory

Tags: swift, macos, alamofire, nsfilemanager

I'm using 'AlamoFireImage' to download my image files.

And after that, I use `NSFileManager` and `CreateFile` method to save them in a directory.

But when I try to retrieve the saved images, It only returns the first File. While It should have saved 15 images.

> Here's my function for saving Image Files :

```
func getImage(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request("https://www.tandori.ir/uploads/categories/" + url).responseImage { (response) in
        if response.result.value != nil {
            do {
                let fileManager = FileManager.default
                let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(url)
                let image = UIImage(named: url)
                let imageData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)
                fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
                print(paths)
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

> And this is my function for downloading them :

```
func launchApp() {
    let imgTitiles = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "imgsArray")!
    for pic in imgTitiles {
        self.getImage(url: pic as! String)
        print("done")
    }
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTab") as! TandoriTabView
    self.present(resultViewController, animated: true)
}
```

When I try to retrieve the saved images, I get this error on Console :

> "BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory"

I'm trying to Show these images in a collection view.

> Here's my code in my ViewController :

```
//Get Images Directory Path Function.
func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}


//Get Images Function.
func getImage(name : String) -> String {
    _ = FileManager.default
    let imagePAth = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(name)

    return imagePAth

}

 //Show Images in collectionView cells function.
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = categoriesCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "categories", for: indexPath) as! categoriesCell
    let imageAddress = getImage(name: imgTitiles[indexPath.row] as! String) //TheRealShit
    cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageAddress)
    return cell
}
```

What seems to be the Problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your code _to retrieve the saved images_, including the info about when it is called. It may be called before completing all downloads.

Comment: @OOPer code updated.

Comment: I cannot find any code to wait all the images downloaded... And that is the problem.

Comment: Are you getting file extension name with the url?

Comment: Does the file actually exist in the expected location (check using Finder or from the shell)?  You don't check the result of calling `createFile()` at all.

Comment: @OOPer How should I make it wait for all the images to download? Can you write a code as answer for me?

Comment: @Rajesh yes the url contains the file extension. It actually saves only the first item. and that is my problem.

Comment: @trojanfoe How should I check the result? Can you write a code as answer for me?

Comment: Please keep logs for url and check are you getting different url names or not. And try to check with this change "fileManager.createFile to imageData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)"

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Alamofire and cannot write a verifiable code. When I cannot make my code verified, I do not post it as an answer.

Comment: @HamedJavaheri `createFile()` returns a boolean so check that and log an error message.  Also you haven't told us if the file is actually created or not.  I am assuming your mention of "File or directory not found" happens when you attempt to read the file you have written.  Surely it's obvious that the first port of call is to actually check if the file actually exists via Finder/shell?

Comment: @trojanfoe It saves the files incomplete. It downloads 1 completely, and others exist with a size of 0 bytes. So basically the problem is it doesn't download all of them or wait for all of them to download, then proceed.

Comment: @HamedJavaheri Then OOPer is correct in that you need to assume there are no images when you present your viewcontroller and as images are successfully downloaded, you need to send a notification to the view controller to reload the array of loaded images.  I think at the moment you are assuming that all the images download immediately when your view controller is presented.

Comment: @trojanfoe Can you just tell me how can I check when all the images are successfully downloaded? I would appreciate if you write this code as answer for me! Thank you.

Comment: @HamedJavaheri I am not going to do your work for you.  The idea is that the view controller starts with 0 images and as they become available it reloads to display them rather than assuming they are there already.

Answer (score -1):

Actually your using Alamofire downloading images are in asynchronously. Due to this you are only few images when you are showing viewcontroller.  Modify your code to getImage() synchronously in below code. I hope it will work for you.

```
func getImage(url: String) {
   if let image = UIImage(named: url) {
   let fileManager = FileManager.default
   let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(url)
   let imageData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)
            fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
            print(paths)
 }
}
```

Comment: Files can exist quite happily without file extensions though?